# Angular Modal Window Called From Controller Not Formatting Content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, modal-dialog, word-wrap

Prior to submitting a request, I am required to validate the data associated to the request for specific requirements.  I click a submit button to perform the validation.  If any errors are found, I store the error into an field with 
 tags between each error.  I then open my modal window and it displays as follows.

[image]

I added $modal to my controller

I called the modal window 2 different way to get the best results but both display content similarly

my code is listed below

$scope.modal = 
        {
         title: "Title",
         content: "Error Message(s) 
 new message "
        };

```
    $scope.open = function()
    {
     var modalInstance = $modal(
     {
      title: "Title 1",
      content: $scope.modal.content
     });
    };

    var myModal = $modal({
     title: "Title 2",
     content: "Error Message(s) <br /> new message 2",
     show: false
    });

    $scope.showModal = function()
    {
     myModal.$promise.then(myModal.show);
    };

    $scope.hideModal = function()
    {
     myModal.$promise.then(myModal.hide);
    };
```

Neither will wrap the lines properly.

I will need to display the modal window on several different submission based on options selected and data displayed.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my answer.  Using the first option:
scope.modal = { title: "Title", content: "Error Message(s) 
new message " };

```
$scope.open = function()
{
 var modalInstance = $modal(
 {
  title: "Title 1",
  content: $scope.modal.content
 });
};
```

I added  the following:

template: '.../.../modal.tpl.html'

This allowed the process to use the modal template html and the output was formatted correctly.

Thanks for the responses